# MySQL Workbench: Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'VISIBLE' at line 1

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Any ideas why `VISIBLE` below is causing an issue?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `setting` (
  `uuid` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `type` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `code` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'An unique name.',
  `value` MEDIUMTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_on` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `updated_on` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`))
ENGINE = MyISAM
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `name_UNIQUE` ON `setting` (`code` ASC) VISIBLE;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `uuid_UNIQUE` ON `setting` (`uuid` ASC) VISIBLE;
```

Errors:

> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `name_UNIQUE` ON `setting` (`code` ASC) VISIBLE
>   Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'VISIBLE' at line 1
>
> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `uuid_UNIQUE` ON `setting` (`uuid` ASC) VISIBLE
>   Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'VISIBLE' at line 1

No error if I remove `VISIBLE` but **MySQL Workbench 8.0.12** auto generates that. How can I stop MySQL Workbench from doing that?

My MySQL info in my Ubuntu 18.04:

> MySQL version: 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 through PHP extension MySQLi

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The problem here is the difference in syntax across different MySQL server versions. It seems that **MySQL Workbench 8.0.12** is auto-generating `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX` statement for the MySQL server **version 8.0**.

From the [MySQL Server 8.0 Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html), the syntax for `CREATE INDEX` is:

```
CREATE [UNIQUE | FULLTEXT | SPATIAL] INDEX index_name
    [index_type]
    ON tbl_name (key_part,...)
    [index_option]
    [algorithm_option | lock_option] ...

key_part: {col_name [(length)] | (expr)} [ASC | DESC]

index_option:
    KEY_BLOCK_SIZE [=] value
  | index_type
  | WITH PARSER parser_name
  | COMMENT 'string'
  | {VISIBLE | INVISIBLE}  /* Notice the option of VISIBLE / INVISIBLE */

index_type:
  USING {BTREE | HASH}
```

However, this option of `{VISIBLE | INVISIBLE}` is not available in the **MySQL Server 5.7**. From [Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html):

```
CREATE [UNIQUE | FULLTEXT | SPATIAL] INDEX index_name
    [index_type]
    ON tbl_name (key_part,...)
    [index_option]
    [algorithm_option | lock_option] ...

key_part:
    col_name [(length)] [ASC | DESC]

index_option:
    KEY_BLOCK_SIZE [=] value
  | index_type
  | WITH PARSER parser_name
  | COMMENT 'string'   /* No option of VISIBLE / INVISIBLE */

index_type:
    USING {BTREE | HASH}
```

---

If you are not looking to upgrade to latest version of MySQL; you can disable this feature of auto-generating with `VISIBLE / INVISIBLE` index:

In MySQL Workbench:

Go to:

> Edit > Preferences > Modeling > MySQL.

Then, set the "Default Target MySQL Version" to **5.7**

Check the screenshot below:

[image: MySQL WorkBench Modeling]

Comment: thanks. any ideas how I can upgrade to MySQL server version 8.0?

Comment: @laukok You may follow the steps given in this link: https://www.tecmint.com/install-mysql-8-in-ubuntu/

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya `VISIBLE` was still generated when transferring schema from one 5.7 server to another, even with Default Target MySQL Version 5.7 set. It seems like a bug of MySQL Workbench 8.0.19-2 in Manjaro Linux.

Comment: @kkzxak47 Please report a bug following the instructions here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/workbench-reporting-bugs.html

Comment: I had the same issue with MariaDB 10.3.27 and MySQL Workbench 8.0.22. Setting the Target MySQL Version to 5.7 in MySQL Workbench did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

in Workbench:
Model > Model Options ... > MySQL
=> uncheck "Use defaults from global settings

Answer (score 2):

Alternative version to 5.7 or 6.3. I used 6.3. On Model>Model Options..>MySql>6.3