# I tried to forward engineer a mysql model, but it won't work

Tags: mysql, database

I don't know what is wrong with the syntax. Can somebody explain this error?

Executing SQL script in server

> ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '),   `voornaam` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
>   `tussenvoegsel` VARCHAR(45) NULL,   `ach' at line 2

SQL Code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `FYS_Database`.`Persoon` (

      `id_persoon` VARCHAR(9) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (),
      `voornaam` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `tussenvoegsel` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `achternaam` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `geboorte_datum` DATE NOT NULL,
      `geslacht` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
      `gebruikers_naam` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `wachtwoord` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `telefoonnummer` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `foto` BLOB NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id_persoon`),
      UNIQUE INDEX `id_persoon_UNIQUE` (`id_persoon` ASC) VISIBLE)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Comment: Why do you have `GENERATED ALWAYS AS ()` when you are not defining any expression.

Comment: Also remove the `VISIBLE` keyword.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Workbench: Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'VISIBLE' at line 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52785125/mysql-workbench-error-in-query-1064-syntax-error-near-visible-at-line-1)

Comment: As a german native speaker I am glad I looked up `tussenvoegsel` No, it does not translate to `Tussenvögel`. ;)